# Kivy: How do I format the x-axis tick labels?

Tags: python, time, graph, kivy, label

I'm using epoch time for my x-axis to plot a real-time graph, however as you can see from this screenshot

[image]

It's not exactly human readable. The green line is current activity and the red line represents the history. The data for my graph is being fed from elsewhere every second, you can plot whatever you want really as long as the value is between 0 - 100 (unless you change the `ymin` and `ymax`

```
class CPUGraph(Graph):
    """Graph to show CPU data over time"""

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CPUGraph, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.start_time = int(time.time())
        self.window_res = 300  # In seconds
        self.xlabel= "Time"
        self.ylabel = "CPU Usage (%)"
        self.y_ticks_major = 10
        self.y_grid_label = True
        self.x_grid_label = True
        self.x_grid = True
        self.y_grid = True
        self.padding = 10
        self.xmin = self.start_time
        self.xmax = self.start_time + self.window_res
        self.x_ticks_major = self.window_res/10
        self.ymin = 0
        self.ymax = 100
        self.tick_color = 1, 1, 1, 1
        self.background_color = 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 1
        self.draw_border = False
        self.label_options = {'color': [1, 1, 1, 1]}

        self.data = []

       self.cpu_usage = LinePlot(color=[1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.85], line_width=2)
       self.current_usage = LinePlot(color=[0, 1, 0, 1], line_width=2)

       self.add_plot(self.current_usage)
       self.add_plot(self.cpu_usage)

   def update_plot(self, data_point):
       """Update plot with list of currently collected data"""

        if len(self.data) > (self.window_res * 0.95):
            self.xmax += 1
            self.xmin += 1

        self.data.append(data_point)
        self.cpu_usage.points = [((x + self.start_time), y) for x, y in enumerate(self.data)]
        self.current_usage.points = [(x, data_point) for x in range(self.xmin, self.xmax + 1)]
```

Comment: what is your question?, 
What kind of graphics do you expect?

Comment: @eyllanesc, thanks for embedding the screenshot. The time displayed at each major tick on the x-axis is in epoch time. I want to be able to display the time in a human readable format instead (15:03:24 for example) The issue I'm having is that the epoch time makes it easier to plot points on the graph as it's easier to work in seconds. My question is can I format the x-axis tick labels?